# Spotify Play button issues since Web Player introduction

Tags: web-services, api, spotify

Our website has been having some issues with the Spotify Play button since the Spotify Web player has come into existence.

There are **3 issues** that I have noticed so far:

1) **Have to click twice to get the track to play**

Clicking the play button (when the Web player didn't exist) used to start the song playback in the background.  Now on clicking the button, it first launches the web player (which is fine) but doesn't automatically start playing the music. It imports the playlist but that's all it does. It works only if the user manually presses play on the Web Player/ Clicks on the button the second time (bad from a usability perspective - left our users confused).  Along with this, to confuse users further, The Play Button shows "The Track Cannot be played" when this happens. However, if you press on that track again (either from the play button or the actual web player), it works fine and the message goes away. 
Tested on Chrome (OSX and Windows 7) , Safari (OSX)
Can be replicated here: http://partysen.se/event/5/tanmays-awesome-party/

[image: Screenshot of the bug on my web app]

2) **Invalid OAuth Token**

A possibly connected problem seen since the launch of the web player is the play button saying "Invalid OAuth Token" when trying to play something. I do not have much more information to replicate it, other than the fact that it started happening on Mac OSX once the web player was launched and I also installed the mac spotify app. 
Tested on Chrome (OSX and Windows 7) , Safari (OSX)

3) **Button asks for App Installation**

Another issue : On clicking the play button a spotify web page asks for installation of the app. Also discussed here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348049/spotify-play-button-not-working-in-google-chrome

Noticed this only in Chrome in Mac OSX.

**Questions**

Is it possible to fix if the button uses the Desktop apps or the Web Player in the mean time ?

Can we get any more information regarding the OAuth Error described above?

Comment: It would appear that even the play button on Spotify's own documentation also has the same error if you have the Spotify client - https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-play-button/